# How to properly implement a back button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to display a back button in my app, which would allow the user to navigate backward through the history stack.

The problem here is that if the user came to the app from another link, then the home page will display the back button.

If the user opens a new tab and manually goes to the app, they won't see the back button, but if they try signing in, which will redirect them to the home page, they'll see the back button on the home page.

I'd provide code for the back button, but that's not really what my question is about. I know the `location` object has a `key` property that is undefined on first render, but that hasn't helped me solve this issue.

Has anyone managed to properly implement a back button in their application, that will show up only in places they require?

Comment: are you using a routing library like react router? also what's wrong with the back button on the browser?

Comment: Yes I am and there nothing wrong with the back button on the browser, I just felt like it'd be a better UX.

Comment: What about keeping track of url history in state somewhere? That's a fairly easy thing to accomplish, just listen for location changes somewhere, maybe even in your back button. If the length is 0 don't show the button -- and remove the last entry the stack when they click back. the back button in the browser will mess with that though. thats why you don't see this UX a lot, giving users two ways of doing stuff is not great

Comment: That's fair, I guess I'll try tracking the history with redux. Thank you.

Comment: redux or component state, either is fine. I recommend using a dummy Route component that renders on all urls, or use one of react rotuers new hooks create a state change as an effect of location change

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for? Using react router I have something like navigate back to dashboard on some of my pages in my application.

I have components/shared/Button. It takes as props two params destination and text.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const BackButton = (props) => {
  const { dest, text } = props;

  return (
    <Button variant="secondary" href={`${dest}`}>{text}</Button>
  );
};

BackButton.propTypes = {
  dest: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default BackButton;
```

Usage.

```
<BackButton dest="/" text="Back to Dashboard" />
```

Hope it helps.